# How do You Insert New Relations in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-api

I am trying to find the syntax for inserting a new Relation between issues in Redmine using Ruby.

The code I've been trying:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_resource'
class Issue < ActiveResource::Base
     self.site = '[the site]'
     self.user = '[the user]'
     self.password = '[the password]' #not hard coded
     self.format = :json #I've had issues with Issue.find(i) without explicitly stating the format
end

class IssueRelation < ActiveResource::Base
     self.site = '[the site]'
     self.user = '[the user]'
     self.password = '[the password]' #not hard coded
     self.format = :json #I've had issues with Issue.find(i) without explicitly stating the format
end

issue1 = Issue.find(1)
issue2 = Issue.find(2)

puts issue1.id
puts issue2.id

relation = IssueRelation.new(
    :issue => issue1,
    :issue_to => issue2,
    :relation_type => 'relates'
    )

if relation.save
    puts relation.id
else
    puts relation.errors.full_message
end
```

The output I get back:

```
1
2
...'handle_response': Failed. Response code = 404. Response Message = not found.
```

The output suggests that Issue 1 and 2 were successfully found, but that the name I'm using for the relation is not valid, hence the 404 not found.

What is the correct syntax for creating a relation in Redmine's API given that I have found the two issues that it will link?

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the solution to this.

Rather than use the IssueRelation object you need to use the Relation object.

Also, before using the Relation object you must change the site.

```
Relation.site="[the site]/issues/#{issue1.id}/"
rel = Relation.new(
       :issue_to_id => issue2.id,
       :relation_type => 'relates'
      )
rel.save
```

You could probably put :site in the Relation.new instead of changing it for the class.